Search Kit Match pattern
I am trying to run a search that would return first names that are random string of letters/numbers. We had a lot of spam come through a signup form, where first names look like "sldkfmVUnkdUnnns" or any other random string of letters. I was hoping I can use search kit to find first names that are longer than normal? I tried to use "matches pattern" but I'm not sure what to do.
Does anyone have a good solution for finding these spam records?

interesting solution in those answers. spam also often comes with 'first = last' just in case that has affected you and gives you a/ another way to find delete, b/ another tool to add to your forms to prevent these.

Using SearchKit -
To filter on first name > 12 characters -
First Name - Matches Pattern - ^[a-z]{12,}

Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10
Or this one may also be useful, find contacts with more than 1 uppercase letter in their first name -
First Name - Matches Pattern (case sensitive) - [A-Z].*[A-Z]

Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900903/regex-to-detect-a-word-with-more-than-1-capital-letters
